# Obtaining XtextResource from EObject tree (model)

Tags: eclipse-emf, xtext

For the sake of simplicity say I have multiple Xtext DSLs that all describe some sort of query. One of them is my "base" DSL. I now would like to translate one of my DSLs to my "base" DSL and retrieve the string representation of the model.

I created a EFactory via

```
MyDslFactory factory = new MyDslFactoryImpl();
```

Then I manually traverse the source-DSL's XtextResource (I got that from the EmbeddedEditor) and use the target-DSL factory to build my model (EObject tree).
Now I would like to get the text representation of that model but this is where I get stuck. I know how to get the string representation of a XtextResource so I guess that's the way to go, but I don't know how to create the XtextResource from the EObject-tree.

In org.eclipse.xtext.junit.AbstractXtextTests there is a method

```
 doGetResource(InputStream in, URI uri)
```

but now I don't find a way to get an InputStream from my model.

Is there a way to create the XtextResource from the object tree or is there a simpler way to do what I would like to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text serialization, you should obtain an instance of org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.ISerializer using injection.

Make sure you have defined some formatting rules in Formatter, otherwise the readability of the output is a bit "limited" ;-)